# How can I create resizing spacers in JavaFX?

Tags: layout, javafx

First of all, I'm a long time Java/Swing developer. I recently installed JavaFX 2.2 to play around with.

I'm creating a fairly simple app, whose main window has a toolbar on top and content in the rest of the window. The obvious way to accomplish this is to use a `BorderPane`, and stick a `ToolBar` into the top section. So far, so good. However, I would like some of the controls in the toolbar to be at the left edge of the window, and some at the right edge. I can find no way to do this. I can put an invisible spacer object into the toolbar, but I only know how to give it a fixed width; it doesn't resize when the window is resized.

So I thought that instead of using a ToolBar object, I'll just use an `HBox`; it should be equivalent to a horizontally-oriented Swing `Box` object, right? And the Swing `Box` class has a `createHorizontalGlue()` method that inserts an auto-sizing spacer. Well, I can't find an equivalent in the JavaFX HBox class. Is there no simple way to do this?

Answer (score 13):

I figured out how to do it using an `HBox` instead of a `ToolBar` to hold the controls; the key is the `HBox.setHgrow()` method, which allows you to set a spacer object to grow to fill the available space. I still don't know if it's possible to do this with an actual ToolBar instance.

```
/**
 * Creates and populates the Node that serves as the window toolbar.
 *
 * @return a newly constructed and populated toolbar component
 */
private Node makeToolbar() {
    // Auto-sizing spacer
    Region spacer = new Region();
    HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);

    // Horizontal box containing toolbar controls
    HBox box = new HBox();
    box.setPadding(new Insets(8));
    box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    box.getChildren().addAll(openButton, spacer, resizeSlider);

    // Colored background panel with drop shadow
    Pane bgRect = new Pane();
    bgRect.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #e0e0e0;");
    bgRect.setEffect(DropShadowBuilder.create().width(1).build());

    // StackPane to hold box and rectangle
    StackPane stack = new StackPane();
    stack.getChildren().addAll(bgRect, box);

    return stack;
}
```

Comment: James Weaver's article [Best Practices for JavaFX 2.0 Enterprise Applications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafxbest2-1634274.html) demonstrates placing a resizing spacer (termed a spring in the article) inside a ToolBar.  The static HGrow setting used for the spring is the same as your answer (because internally a horizontal ToolBar is just an HBox).

Comment: Thanks, jewelsea; that's a much simpler solution!

Answer (score 8):

i do it this way:

```
private Node makeFooter(Node left, Node right) {
        ToolBar footer = new ToolBar();
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);     
        spacer.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        footer.getItems().addAll(left, spacer, right);
        return footer;
}
```

hope i could help someone

Answer (score 0):

One can also use a vertically- or horizontally-oriented [separator control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Separator.html) in Scene Builder. Make sure to set its `Hgrow` property to `ALWAYS` to ensure it resizes with the window at all times.